# AIDL - What's the point?

Tags: service, callback, aidl, android

Ok so I have an android app with an Activity (UI) and a Service (background polling).  The two are intricately connected using AIDL (including callbacks so it's duplex communication, IPC, whatever).

Any time the two talk I'm using that.

However I have also extended the Application class - so that the two can share common data objects.  So the Application holds a User object that the Service is always using, and the Activity can also access it when it's running.

The Application also has a WeakReference to the Activity (to avoid context leaks) because the User will sometimes trigger UI updates.

So it looks like

`Activity (UI) ---> Application <--- Service`

I can trigger UI events within the Service by doing

```
_app = (FooApplication)this.getApplication();
FooActivity uiRef = _app.getUIReference().get();
if (uiRef != null) {
   uiRef.updateSomeDisplay();
}
```

So I don't get it.  Why bother with complex AIDL calls when I just weak reference the UI, see if it exists, and call its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of AIDL is to allow inter-process communication. The point of a service is to allow background operations to run in a separate process from your UI thread, so that they can continue running even if you close your app. You'll need AIDL, because your service will run in a completely different process from your UI, so you won't have access to memory in the UI process from your Service process.

Comment: I see.  I kinda had been piecing this same thought together and had come back to edit myself.  If I have a separate process - would a standalone service process not appear in Advanced Task Killer?  Is that limited to listing Activities?

Comment: I've been working with background services in multiple applications for the last year on all kinds of devices from Android 2.1 up to 4.1.2 and have never once seen a service running in a separate process from a user interface defined in the same .apk file.  The documentation says "If an application component starts and there already exists a process for that application (because another component from the application exists), then the component is started within that process and uses the same thread of execution."  Yes, you *can* tell it not to do this, but I see no reason why you would...?

Comment: One example of why you'd want to do this is for a background audio service. If you make the player run in a separate process, then your media player app can be more memory efficient, because the entire UI stack doesn't have to remain in memory while your audio playing. However, it does complicate things considerably to use AIDL, so in most cases, it's not worth it.